# logging in via iframe

Tags: javascript, authentication, sharepoint, iframe

I'm trying to make a SharePoint App where on page load, an iframe loads a login screen. The reason why I'm using an iframe is because the site is already fully built out and for right now (band-aid fix) want to to just render the site within an iframe in SharePoint on page load. No problem there and it works great. However, the page that I'm rendering is a logon screen asking for credentials in order to logon to the console. Anytime I try and authenticate, it just refreshes the page. I then typed in invalid credentials and get the expected 'invalid logon creds' error.

I tried going to other sites that make you login and got the exact same behaivior. I have read some stuff on google that is saying an iFrame isn't the tool for this so I'm wondering what my options are. Thanks in advance for any helpful input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding this thread: [Logging in via iFrame doesn't work with IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116106/logging-in-via-iframe-doesnt-work-with-ie9)

I think I am correct. An iframe isn't a correct design here.